# Cannot update image using fileupload in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, input, updatemodel

I am trying to update the text and images which is already updated to the databases. I have got a admin section in which there is a news menu, where the user can edit and update the news with images. The problem is i can edit and update the news text but the images doesnt update . Below is the controller and view :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        INewsRepository newsResp = new NewsRepository();
        News news = newsResp.GetNews(id);

        if (TryUpdateModel(news)){
            newsResp.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }else{
            return View();
        }
    }
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                  { %>

                <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px;">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                Title</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { style = "width:300px;" })%>
                                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)%>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                Article content</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Article, new { @class = "tinymce" })%>
                                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Article)%>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Image 1
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <img height="56px" width="75px" alt="image1" src="/content/images/content/<%: Model.ImageLarge %>" />
                            <br />

                            <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Image 2
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <img height="56px" width="75px" alt="image1" src="/content/images/content/<%: Model.ImageLarge2 %>" />
                            <br />

                            <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Image 3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img height="56px" width="75px" alt="image1" src="/content/images/content/<%: Model.ImageLarge3 %>" />
                            <br />

                            <input type="file" name="files" id="file3" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </p>
                <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TryUpdateModel` won't update files. You could manually copy the streams into the corresponding property of your `News` model:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
    file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    news.Files.Add(buffer);
}
```

Comment: is it the right way of uploading pictures , what i was thinking to save the images in the folder and just save the name of the file on the database

Comment: @Muhammad Awais, yes, that seems a good way of handling file uploads. If the files are big it would be better to store them on the file system and store the actual name and path in the database.